# Splunk - Match different fields in different events from same data source

Tags: splunk

I have a data source in which I need to return all pairs of events (event1, event2) from a single data source, where field1 from event1 matches field2 from event2.

For example, let's say I have the following data.

[image]

I need to return a pair of events where field **id** from event1, matches field **referrer_id** from event2. Let's say, to get the following report.

- Adam Anderson referred Betty Burger on 2016-01-02 08:00:00.000
- Adam Anderson referred Carol Camp on 2016-01-03 08:00:00.000
- Betty Burger referred Darren Dougan on 2016-01-04 08:00:00.000

In sql I can do this quite easily with the following command.

```
select a.first_name as first1, a.last_name as last1, b.first_name as first2,
       b.last_name as last2, b.date as date
from myTable a
inner join myTable b on a.id = b.referrer_id;
```

Which returns the following table,

[image]

which gives exactly the data I need.

Now, I've been attempting to replicate this in a splunk query and have run into quite a few issues. First I attempted to use the transaction command, but that aggregated all of the related events together as opposed to matching them a pair at a time.

Next, I attempted to use a subsearch, first finding the **id** and then searching in the subsearch, first for the first event by **id** and the appending the second event by **referral_id**. Then, since **append** creates a new row instead of appending to the same row, using a **stats** to aggregate the resulting rows by the matching id field. I did attempt to use **appendcols** but that didn't return anything for me.

```
...
| table id
| map search="search id=$id$
  | fields first_name, last_name, id
  | rename first_name as first1
  | rename last_name as last1
  | rename id as match_id
  | append [search $id$
    | search referral_id=$id$
    | fields first_name, last_name, referral_id, date
    | rename first_name as first2
    | rename last_name as span2
    | rename referral_id as match_id]"
| fields first1, last1, first2, last2, match_id, time
| stats values(first1) as first1, values(last1) as last1, values(first2) as first2,
  values(last2) as last2, values(time) as time by id
```

The above query works for me and gives me the table I need, but it is incredibly slow due to the repeated searches over the entire time frame, and also limited by the map **maxsearches** which, for whatever reason, cannot be set to unlimited.

This seems like an overly complicated solution, especially in comparison to the sql query. Surely there must exist a simpler, faster way that this can be done, which isn't limited by the arbitrary limited settings or the multiple repeating search queries. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you considered [`join`](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Join)?

Comment: I've considered join. It didn't return all the results I needed - it would only return two rows instead of three, matching A on B only, instead of matching A on B and on C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using append. Using join gave me faster results, but didn't result in every matching pair, for my example it would return 2 rows instead of three, returning Adam with Betty, but not returning Adam with Carol.

Using append returned a full list, and using stats by id gave me the result I was looking for, a full list of each matching pair. It also gave extra empty fields, so I had to remove those, and then manipulate the resulting mv's into their own individual rows. Splunk doesn't offer a multifield mv expand, so I used a workaround.

```
...
| rename id as matchId, first_name as first1, last_name as last1
| table matchId, first1, last1
| append [
  search ... 
  | rename referrer_id as matchId, first_name as first2, last_name as last2
  | table matchId, first2, last2, date]
| stats list(first1) as first1, list(last1) as last1, list(first2) as first2, list(last2) as last2, list(date) as date by matchId
| search first1!=null last1!=null first2!=null last2!=null
| eval zipped=mvzip(mvzip(first2, last2, ","), date, ",")
| mvexpand zipped
| makemv zipped delim=","
| eval first2=mvindex(zipped, 0)
| eval last2=mvindex(zipped, 1)
| eval date=mvindex(zipped, 2)
| fields - zipped
```

This is faster than using a map with multiple subsearches, and gives all the of results. It is still limited by the maximum size of the subsearch, but at least provides the necessary data.